# Javascript: Getting a Single Property Name

Tags: javascript

Given an object like this:

```
{ name: "joe" }
```

I want to get the value "name". I know I can use the for construct to iterate over the properties in an object, but the objects I'll be dealing with will always have a single key:value pair, and I won't know the name of the property. To further illustrate:

```
var a = { age: 24 };
console.log(myFunc(a)) // Displays "age"

var b = { job: "cook" };
console.log(myFunc(b)) // Displays "job"
```

Is there anyway to do this without iterating over the object? Also I'd like to do this in pure Javascript. No frameworks/libs involved.

Comment: Maybe you should use an array instead `a=["age",24"]`, and then you get the name with `a[0]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is good practice to use `.hasOwnProperty` to ensure you aren't returning a property from the Object prototype:

```
function myFunc(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) return prop;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm curious if it's worth the additional function call. My testing (In Firefox) shows the object prototypes always come last during iteration. Maybe that's not the case in all browsers?

Comment: @mellowsoon, I was about to come with that, in IE8 and below, inherited properties are enumerated at first! (try [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/cmsalvado/cuFeK/) in IE<=8), if you want the first enumerable **own property** you should use `hasOwnProperty`, although I would use `if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop))` (maybe storing a ref. to the method to make it fast), to make it *safer*, since an object *could* have a property named `hasOwnProperty`, and that property will *shadow* the method from `Object.prototype`. Anyway this should be the accepted answer, +1 to @Ryan :)

Comment: After researching the hasOwnProperty() function a bit more, I see how important it is. So I've changed this to the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be about the best you can get:

```
function myFunc(v) {
  for (var x in v) { return { prop: x, val: v[x] }; }
  return null;
};
```

Comment: For fun, clarity, or maybe I'm just incompetent... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, iteration is the only well-supported way to get the property name. So `for...in` time it is. Just hide it in a function and it'll look fine.

However, it might also be worth thinkin about whether you should be using a different kind of object for your purpose, say, `{"property": "age", "value": 24}`, or even `["age", 24]`

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the object's properties and simply return the first one.

```
function myFunc(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Edit: oops, you wanted the property name, not the value

Comment: You should *really* use `var prop ...` in the `for-in` statement, otherwise `prop` will become global (`window.prop`), or if it exist higher in the scope chain, it will be overwritten.

Comment: @CMS Thanks, I even forgot to do that in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not iterate? It's just one step. I don't think you can get it in any other way. You can even break after the first step if it makes you feel better.