# Getting name of object as a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enumerate the properties of a javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object)
>   [Javascript: Getting a Single Property Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982721/javascript-getting-a-single-property-name)

Given a JavaScript object or JSON object such as:

```
{
  property: "value"
}
```

How can one get the word `property` as a string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85992/how-do-i-enumerate-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(var i in obj) alert(i);//the key name
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var obj = {
    property: "value"
};

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        alert("key = " + key + ", value = " + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One brutal way would be to use .toString on the object and then extract the name. But i'm sure there would be better ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.keys()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
var key = Object.keys( my_obj )[ 0 ];  // "property"
```

It returns an Array of the enumerable keys in that specific object (not its prototype chain).

---

To support older browsers, include the compatibility shim provided in the MDN docs.

```
if (!Object.keys) {
    Object.keys = function (o) {
        if (o !== Object(o)) throw new TypeError('Object.keys called on non-object');
        var ret = [],
            p;
        for (p in o) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, p)) ret.push(p);
        return ret;
    }
}
```